# Movie/series/books where these children go to a magical land, but it has a lot of dark history to the story

Tags: story-identification, isekai

So I can’t remember much, even if it’s a book or movie (or both), but basically I thought the premise was that these kids enter this magical world (similar-ish to *The Chronicles of Narnia*), but they eventually find out that like their uncle or someone close to them had once traveled to the same magical land as a kid, but he couldn’t travel there once he became an adult.

And they also discover that there’s a history of some adult in the family sexually abusing other children in the family (who are also now adults or committed suicide or something else pretty dark). So it kind of makes you question if this magical world was even real or just a figment of imagination of this abused child as a means of escapism. Also, I think the abuser was someone who was originally held up on a pedestal, so that was a big plot twist revealing that this man revered in the magical world was actually a terrible person.

Did I dream this crazy story up or was this actually the plot to a story or movie?

Comment: If someone posts a correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 5):

Expanding upon NoddySpice's answer, in Lev Grossman's *The Magicians* trilogy, the [Chatwin Family](https://themagicians.fandom.com/wiki/Chatwin_Family) travel to the magical land of Fillory through the grandfather clock in the house of their novelist neighbor, [Christopher Plover](https://themagicians.fandom.com/wiki/Christopher_Plover). Subsequently, he wrote a well-regarded series of novels featuring their adventures as fiction, *Fillory and Further*. It is later revealed that Plover abused one of the children, [Martin](https://themagicians.fandom.com/wiki/The_Beast), who found a way to stay in Fillory as an adult, albeit as The Beast, mutated by the Wellspring.

Other than the reveal of Plover's abuse, it is later revealed that the primary villain of the *Fillory* series of books was actually a heroic figure whose intents were misunderstood by the Chatwin children and further villainized by Plover in his novels.

The idea of the magical land possibly being a delusion could also tie in with how Grossman apparently wrote the sequels in part because some people theorized that the magic in the first book was a delusion by Quentin.

> Lev Grossman has said that part of the reason he wrote the sequels was to refute all the theorists who were convinced that all the magic in the first book was actually a series of psychotic hallucinations and that Quentin had killed himself at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds a bit like *The Magicians* by Lev Grossman.

The kids in that series travel to a mythical/magical land, and there was also the abuser plot twist too.
This is based off seeing 4 seasons of the TV show not the actual book.

Comment: That came to mind to, but can you expand upon why this would be a match?