# Interview where Lev Grossman stated that he wrote the Magicians sequels in response to people thinking the magic of the first book was a hallucination

Tags: story-identification, behind-the-scenes, the-magicians

In my answer to the question [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/283501/23243), I quote a piece from the TV Tropes entry for *[The Magicians](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/TheMagicians)*, which stated

> Lev Grossman has said that part of the reason he wrote the sequels was to refute all the theorists who were convinced that all the magic in the first book was actually a series of psychotic hallucinations and that Quentin had killed himself at the end.

It bothers me a bit to quote that without a source. The closest I've found so far is [this interview](https://www.avclub.com/lev-grossman-1798226874) where he discusses Quentin being a very different person in the later books.

> It was a relief to come back to Quentin and have this sense that he’d grown up a bit. He’s 17 when *The Magicians* begins, but he’s a young 17. His emotional range is not giant, and he’s full of angst about things that really relate to him and not to anybody else. He’s kind of bullshit, in a way, which I thought was appropriate and psychologically accurate for people like him, which is like the 17-year-old I used to be. But over the course of *The Magicians*, he gets over some of his bullshit, and it was a relief to write him and come back to him where he doesn’t have to be pounding his fist all the time and wondering if he’s gonna get to sleep with every woman he meets. That adolescent shit was kind of, “Just take it off the table, and you can find the larger emotional range for Quentin.” That was a relief, and it was good. It was a lot more fun.

Comment: Maybe it would be possible to track down the user who added the edit? The TV Tropes page history says it's someone called AnotherEpicFail and was added on Jul 15th 2020 at 12:00:08 AM.

Comment: They let me know that they were just copying over an entry from another location. Unfortunately, the person who posted that one hasn't posted since 2021, have I still left them a message, just in case.